# incompatible return type ReadOnlyLongWrapper in lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, javafx, treetableview

I'm trying to create a `TreeTableView` and trying to set sell value factory to

```
    @FXML
    private TreeTableColumn<Good, Long> folderId;
```

here:

```
 folderId.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Good, Long> param) ->
                new ReadOnlyLongWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getFolderId()));
```

I get this underlined red with the error described in the title. `getFolderId`
in `Good` class is the following:

```
public Long getFolderId() {
        return folderId;
    }
```

the same method works fine for String or Boolean values but drops an exception mentioned in title and the following on compilation:

```
incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
    javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyLongWrapper cannot be converted to javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue<java.lang.Long>
```

how to get `ObservableValue<java.lang.Long>` instead of `ReadOnlyLongWrapper` and why this exception appears only with Long values?

here is the whole method:

```
goodsPane.setCenter(goodTreeTableView);
        List<Good> goodAndFoldersList = goodsService.getGoods();
        List<Good> goods = new ArrayList<Good>();
        List<Good> roots = new ArrayList<Good>();
        for (Good good: goodAndFoldersList){
            if (good.isIs_folder()) {
                roots.add(good);
            }else {
                goods.add(good);
            }
        }
        TreeItem<Good> rootItem = new TreeItem<>();
        for (Good root: roots){
            Long folderId = root.getId();
            TreeItem<Good> rootTreeItem = new TreeItem<>(root);
            for (Good good: goods){
                if (good.getFolderId() == folderId){
                    TreeItem<Good> goodTreeItem = new TreeItem<>(good);
                    rootTreeItem.getChildren().add(goodTreeItem);
                }
            }
            rootItem.getChildren().add(rootTreeItem);
        }
        goodTreeTableView.setRoot(rootItem);
        goodName.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Good, String> param) ->
                new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getName()));
        folderId.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Good, Long> param) ->
                new ReadOnlyLongWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getFolderId()));
        is_folder.setCellValueFactory((TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Good, Boolean> param) ->
                new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().isIs_folder()));
```

Answer (score 3):

[`ReadOnlyLongWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyLongWrapper.html) is an `ObservableValue<Number>`.

So there are two solutions at hand:

1. Change your column to `TreeTableColumn<Good, Number> folderId;` or
2. Create your own implementation of `ObservableValue<Long>`.

In most cases, 1 should be just fine, as you can do [`Number.longValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#longValue--).